# Missing Attribute Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working with Rails, and when setting up some tests I encountered:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
can't write unknown attribute `group_id`
```

I'm guessing the issue is in my relations. I have

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :transactions
    has_many :users
end
```

And

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :group 
    belongs_to :user
end
```

And lastly,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :group
    has_many :transactions
end
```

I saw that someone had the same error because they were using `has_one` rather than `belongs_to` and needed to add an ID column to their DB.  I'm using `belongs_to` though, so I don't think that's what I need? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have the `group_id` column in your db.

You must remember that Rails is built on top of a [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database), which means that you can access "related" data by referencing a [`foreign_key`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key).

When setting up a `belongs_to` / `has_many` association, the `belongs_to` table needs to have the appropriate foreign key (in your case `group_id`):

[image]

Your error doesn't state which model you're receiving the exception for; I would hazard a guess that it's `User` or `Transaction`.

--

To fix it, I would recommend creating a migration to add the `group_id` attribute to the appropriate model:

```
$ rails g migration AddGroupId

#db/migrate/add_group_id____________.rb
class AddGroupID < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      add_column :users, :group_id, :integer
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you created the model you are referring to with a migration that had references, you will still need a migration in your database. An easy way to check if the database has one is to visit your `some_project_root/db/schema.rb`. If you don't see a the field you want there then you will have to generate one. The way you would do so is to run a  `rails g migration AddXidToY x_id:integer` . It should set a field up for the id in the table you want.